# how to change the word 'preface' in Scientific Workplace 5.5

Tags: babel, naming

I'm having a problem with the language in SWP 5.5. I am writting a text in spanish, so I am using the `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` sentence at the beginning of the document and it works perfectly with all the format. However, the word 'Preface' still appears in english after the ToC in the pdf output. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

Scientific Workplace (SWP) sadly hasn't been updated properly in years. Version 5.5, still labelled the "current" version, is at least six years old by now. Which version of the `babel` package is shipped with SWP 5.5? I don't know, but it's almost surely both much older than and no longer fully compatible with the current version, which is distributed via the CTAN and is available to users of TeXLive, MacTeX, and MikTeX.

Depending on how old the version of `babel` is that comes with SWP, the interface for changing names such "Preface" may be quite different from what's around in the latest version.